# Al guardar la desactivacion del checkbox solo funciona con el primero en mi tabla

Tags: php, javascript, html

Se ha solucionado la parte de activar el checkbox y enseguida bloquearlo, se guarda mientras no borre el cache del navegador, la cosa es que por cada registro que se inserta en la tabla, se genera un checkbox para cada fila, aquí el problema; el bloqueo y el guardado solo funciona para el primer checkbox, necesito que también lo siguientes lo hagan, aquí el código con el script.

```
<?php
    $salida.="<tr>
                        <td>".$fila['id']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['col1']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['col2']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['col3']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['col4']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['col5']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['col6']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['col7']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['col8']."</td>

                        <td><label class=''><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' id='box' onclick='clicked(this)'><span></span></label></td>
</tr>";
        }
        $salida.="</tbody></table>";
?>

<script>function clicked(checkBox){        
    localStorage.setItem('state', checkBox.checked);
    checkBox.disabled = true;
}

function getState(){
    let state = localStorage.getItem('state');
    if(!state){
        return;
    }
    let checkBox = document.querySelector("#box");
    checkBox.checked = state;
    checkBox.disabled = true;

}

getState()</script>
```

Comment: Los IDs deben ser únicos y tienes `id='box'` para cada checkbox en la fila, por eso te funciona solo con el primero.

Comment: hola @Triby, el detalle que el checkbox hasta insertar y aparecer la fila se verá, esa es mi duda :x

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre que pruebes a que cada checkbox tenga un name distinto, por ejemplo si cada linea la estas sacando de una BBDD y tiene un id la añadas así

```
name='checkbox<?php echo "$fila['id']" ?>'
```

Tendría que ver un poco mas el codigo y saber que es lo que quieres hacer con esos checkbox ¿solo impedir que no se puedan checkear más? o ese check actualiza algo quizás con una conexión asíncrona con ajax?

Comment: solo impedir que no se puedan checkear :)

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero es corregir tu HTML para evitar IDs duplicados, simplemente agregando el ID de la tabla, para que queden `id="box-##"`

```
<?php
    $salida.="<tr>
                        <td>".$fila['id']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['col1']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['col2']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['col3']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['col4']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['col5']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['col6']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['col7']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['col8']."</td>

                        <td><label class=''><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' id='box-".$fila['id']."' onclick='clicked(this);'><span></span></label></td>
</tr>";
        }
        $salida.="</tbody></table>";
?>
```

Luego, tus funciones están preparadas para manejar solo un elemento, pero necesitas usar un arreglo, manejándolo en JSON y guardándolo como cadena en localStorage:

```js
    // Defines el arreglo, donde vas a guardar  id:###, checked:true||false
    let chkStat = [];
    function clicked(box) {
        // Crear formato para guardar en localStorage
        // id y marcado/desmarcado
        let boxData = {'id': box.id, 'checked': box.checked};
        // Agregar a arreglo
        chkStat.push(boxData);
        // Guardar en localStorage convirtiendo el arreglo en una cadena
        // Descomenta la siguiente línea para guardar
        // localStorage.setItem('chkStat', JSON.stringify(chkStat));
        // Desactivar checkbox
        box.disabled = true;
    }
    
    // Al cargar la página, lees lo que hayas guardado
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        // Si falla JSON.parse() se asigna arreglo vacío
        // Descomenta la siguiente línea para leer
        // chkStat = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('chkStat')) || [];
        chkStat.forEach(item => {
            let check = document.querySelector(`#${item.id}`);
            check.checked = item.checked;
            check.disabled = true;
        });
    });
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="box-1" onclick="clicked(this);"> Checkbox 1<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="box-2" onclick="clicked(this);"> Checkbox 2<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="box-3" onclick="clicked(this);"> Checkbox 3<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="box-4" onclick="clicked(this);"> Checkbox 4<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="box-5" onclick="clicked(this);"> Checkbox 5<br>
```

**Nota:** Descomenta las líneas que acceden a localStorage, aquí no se puede acceder.

Comment: muchas gracias @Triby, funcionando, abusare un poco mas, para no crear otro post, ¿sabrás como cambiarle el color al checkbox una vez chekeado y desactivado ?

Comment: solucionado tambien, lo pongo por si le sirve a alguien, solo anexe la clase a mi .css; .checkbox > input:checked:disabled + span::before,
.checkbox > input:indeterminate:disabled + span::before {
    border-color: transparent;
    background-color: #00CD82;
}

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta, por favor márcala como aceptada.